# Boto3 list available services in a region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

In the AWS cli I can get a list of available services when I run

```
aws help
```

Is there a command in `boto3` that allows me to programmatically list available services I can use when initializing a boto3 client?

```
client = boto3.client('<some service>')
```

I can see in the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html), but I'd like the ability to list out the services in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `session.get_available_services()` as per [this documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.get_available_services)

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)

services = session.get_available_services()
```

Comment: This works without the access key if you only want to list the service. Tested with boto version 1.14.35

services = boto3.Session().get_available_services()

Answer (score 1):

While not specifically related to boto3, be aware that you can now query Parameter Store to get useful information, such as:

- which regions are active?
- which services are available in a given region?
- in which regions is a specific service available?

Read [Query for AWS Regions, Endpoints, and More Using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-query-for-aws-regions-endpoints-and-more-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/).